# Importing files from parent directory

Tags: python

I am having some issues importing which results in a module not found error:

Directory structure of project:

```
- MySite
    config.py
    - MySite
          __init__.py
```

Within **init**.py I do the following:

```
import config
```

I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named config
```

I am currently reading this book: https://exploreflask.com/configuration.html which suggests a similar sort of setup.

Do I have to include `__init__.py` under the root directory `MySite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the language documentation (found here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages) when you're importing a package that is in another directory like `- MySite`, depending on your Python version (3.2 or earlier) you need to include `__init__.py` in the directory itself, including the root. Also, when you import, you need to include the directory the package is in, as though they were a package themselves, like so:

```
import MySite.config
```